# how to style a p tag with span in there

Tags: html, css

I have a p tag that has few lines in there , but each line of text is suppose to be a different font size. I added span to be able to access with css and fix that but I have not be able too

```
   <p id="special-text">
                    <span class="special-size24">reserve your </span>
                    <span class="special-size24"> suite now</span>
                    <span class="speciallinetwo"> and get</span>
                    <span> 20&#37;</span>
                    <span>off a tour of the</span>
                    <span>historic</span>
                    <span>gerhard</span>
                    <span>monastery</span>
</p>
```

I gave each span a class...to access with css but didn't make a difference.

css

```
.img-special .special-text .special-size24 { font-size: 24px; }
```

Comment: use `adjacent selector (+)`. but that's not a preferred way.

Comment: give us example of your css too

Comment: you select a class when your <p> has an ID :it is  #special-text and not .special-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving class names to the `span` tags worked for me:

```css
#special-text{}
#special-text .specialline1{font-size:12px;}
#special-text .specialline2{font-size:16px;}
#special-text .specialline3{font-size:20px;}
#special-text .specialline4{font-size:24px;}
#special-text .specialline5{font-size:28px;}
#special-text .specialline6{font-size:32px;}
#special-text .specialline7{font-size:36px;}
```

```html
<p id="special-text">
 <span class="specialline1">reserve your <br> suite now</span>
    <span class="specialline2"> and get</span>
    <span class="specialline3"> 20&#37;</span>
    <span class="specialline4">off a tour of the</span>
    <span class="specialline5">historic</span>
    <span class="specialline6">gerhard</span>
    <span class="specialline7">monastery</span>
</p>
```

Comment: this is the simple and better method.. if OP using `SASS` then its very use to create  a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use nth child

```
#special-text span:nth-child(1){
    color: red; 
} 
#special-text span:nth-child(2){
    color: green; 
} 
#special-text span:nth-child(3){
    color: blue; 
} 
#special-text span:nth-child(4){
    color: yellow; 
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4648zjan/2/)**